# how to send text field values to gmail usinf phonegap javascript

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to send text field information to an email id using cordova plugin phonegap. I googled many sites but there is a code in java.My requirement is in javascript,because I am developing an app which supports android,IOS and windows platforms.So I used cordova plugin.can any one please give any suggestions.Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

hi try [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) plugin this plugins supports android,IOS and windows platforms

**(or)**

if you need javascript only means refer this sites

[ref1](https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782)

[ref2](http://phpjs.org/functions/mail/)

[ref3](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-email-form.phtml)

Comment: thanks for your replay.I don't want to use java and objective c for this.I wanted to do this using javascript.

Comment: for the first link you only need javascript